# bash - use a int variable as an index refering to position parameters passed to a function

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

I would like to use a variable as a index value to refer to positional variables passed to script, e.g.:

```
x=101
y=201
z=301

foo(){

    i=0;
    (( i+=1 )); # i=1
    echo "${$i}"; # parameter 1
    (( i+=1 )); # i=2
    echo "${$i}"; # parameter 2
    (( i+=1 )); # i=3
    echo "${$i}"; # parameter 3
}

foo x y z
```

output:

```
101
201
301
```

Arrays and loops will not help in this case, I need a simple method of incrementing a int variable and using this value as a index to retrieve a method parameter passed.

Advice?

Comment: Tip: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) recognizes common bugs and mistaken attempts to do things, [including this one](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2082).

Comment: You can show the pars with `while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
      echo "Next par is $1 ";
      shift;
   done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need indirect variable expansion here:

```
x=101
y=201
z=301

foo() {
   local i
   local v
   for ((i=1; i<=3; i++ )); do
     v="${!i}" # will get x, y, z
     echo "${!v}" # will get values of $x, $y, $z
   done
}
```

Then call it as:

```
foo x y z

101
201
301
```

Comment: Oh, *that's* what the OP wanted! I completely misread the question.

Comment: "Arrays and loops will not help in this case"

Comment: There are no arrays here and loop is just to save some repeated code. You can remove loop and increment `$i` 3 times as you have in question

Comment: @anubhava my sincerest apologies, I misread and assumed incorrectly, you are right, thank you!